# Abort process when Exception c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I have a function which has multiple function calls

```
 public async Task Initializer()
        {
            try
            {
                await _inject.UpdateFunction();
                await _inject.AccountUpdate();
                await _inject.InsertData(Args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(" Error:{ex.Message} | {ex.StackTrace}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here If 1st method calls gets any exception, need to log exception . So decorated with try catch block. I have some parallel calls to other methods inside UpdateFunction

```
 public async Task UpdateFunction()
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT somedata FROM tblData WHERE deptid = 'Fun-10'";
                var lstData = await _dataAccess.QueryAsync<string>(sql);
                using SemaphoreSlim maxThread = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
                var tasks = lstData.Select(async data =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await maxThread.WaitAsync();
                        await GetIds(data);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.Error($"Error : {ex.Message} | {ex.StackTrace}");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        maxThread.Release();
                    }
                });
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error : {ex.Message} | {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
```

In this case I got some exception in GetIds(), which is decorated by try catch .

If any of the method throws exception, I need to abort Initializer(). I added try catch in
before tasks and tried,currently inside task added try catch, still not able to abort Initializer().

Comment: As a side note, the correct place to put the `await maxThread.WaitAsync();` is just before the `try` block. Otherwise you might release the semaphore without having acquired it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception) inside the `catch` block of the `UpdateFunction` method:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error($"Error : {ex.Message} | {ex.StackTrace}");
    throw;
}
```

This way the error will be propagated to the caller of the method.